# Stack Implementation seg faulting after 30k and 400k+ values

Tags: c++

```
Main.cpp
#include"ArrayStack.cpp" 
#include"DoublingArrayStack.cpp" 
#include"linkedlist.cpp"
#include"stopwatch.cpp" 
int main() { 
DoublingAbstractStack<int>testdoubly(50); 
AbstractStack <int>testfixed(50); 
linkedlist testlinked; 
CStopWatch doubly; 
CStopWatch fixed; 
CStopWatch linked; 

/*fixed.Reset();
for (int i =1; i <= 10000000; i++) { 
    testfixed.push(1); 
    if ( i % 10000 == 0 ) { 
        cout << "time at " << i << " iterations: " << fixed.GetElapsedSeconds() << endl; 
    } 
} 
float fixedend = fixed.GetElapsedSeconds();
cout << "total time for 10M values pushed: " << fixedend << endl; */

doubly.Reset();
for (int i =1; i <= 10000000; i++) { 
    testdoubly.push(1); 
    if ( i % 10000 == 0 ) { 
        cout << "time at " << i << " iterations: " << doubly.GetElapsedSeconds() << endl; 
    } 
} 
float doublyend = doubly.GetElapsedSeconds();
cout << "total time for 10M values pushed: " << doublyend << endl;
}
```

---

```
ArrayStack.cpp
#include <array> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
template <class Type>
class AbstractStack
{
private:
    Type elements; // elements in the array  
    Type max; 
    Type *s;

public:
   AbstractStack(Type num) { //CONSTRUCTOR
        elements= -1; 
        this->max = num; 
        s = new Type[max];
   }

   ~AbstractStack() {delete s; return; } // DESTRUCTOR 

   bool isEmpty() {     //IS EMPTY FUNCTION 
       if (elements== -1) { 
        cout << "no data currently being stored" << endl;
        return true; 
       } 
       else { 
        cout << "Stack not empty" << endl; 
        return false; 
       } 
   }

   int size(void) {      //SIZE FUNCTION
            return elements+1; 
   }

   Type top () {      // TOP VALUE FUNCTION 
   for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) { 
    cout << s[i] << endl; 
   }

        if (elements == -1) {
            cout << "No elements currently in stack" << endl;
        }
        else { 
            return s[elements];
        }           
   }

   Type pop(){         //REMOVING THE TOP VALUE FUNCTION 
       if (isEmpty()) {
            return 0; 
       } 
       else { 
            elements--; 
            return s[elements];
       } 
   }

   void push ( Type e ) {             
       if (elements + 1 == max) { 
            Type *temp = s; 
            delete s; 
            this->max = max + 25;
            s = new Type[max];
            for (int i = 0; i < elements+1; i++) { 
                s[i] = temp[i]; 
            }
            elements++;
            s[elements] = e ;
            return; 
       }
       else { 
            elements++;
            s[elements] = e; 
       } 
   }
};
```

---

```
DoublyArrayStack.cpp
#include <array> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
template <class Type>
class DoublingAbstractStack
{
private:
    Type elements; // elements in the array  
    Type max; 
    Type *s;

public:
   DoublingAbstractStack(Type num) { //CONSTRUCTOR
        elements= -1; 
        this->max = num; 
        s = new Type[max];
   }

   ~DoublingAbstractStack() {delete s; return; } // DESTRUCTOR 

   bool isEmpty() {     //IS EMPTY FUNCTION 
       if (elements== -1) { 
        cout << "no data currently being stored" << endl;
        return true; 
       } 
       else { 
        cout << "Stack not empty" << endl; 
        return false; 
       } 
   }

   int size(void) {      //SIZE FUNCTION
            return elements+1; 
   }

   Type top () {      // TOP VALUE FUNCTION 
   for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) { 
    cout << s[i] << endl; 
   }

        if (elements == -1) {
            cout << "No elements currently in stack" << endl;
        }
        else { 
            return s[elements];
        }           
   }

   Type pop(){         //REMOVING THE TOP VALUE FUNCTION 
       if (isEmpty()) {
            return 0; 
       } 
       else { 
            elements--; 
            return s[elements];
       } 
   }

   void push ( Type e ) {             
       if (elements + 1 == max) { 

            Type *temp = s; 
            delete s; 
            this->max *= 2;
            s = new Type[max];
            for (int i = 0; i < elements+1; i++) { 
                s[i] = temp[i]; 
            }
            elements++;
            s[elements] = e ;
            return; 
       }
       else { 
            elements++;
            s[elements] = e; 
       } 
   }
};
```

my ArrayStack is seg faulting at roughly 35k values stored and my doublyArraystack is seg faulting at roughly 405k values stored and I have no idea why if anyone is able to explain why that is. My linked list version of this runs through 10M values in ~1.2 seconds but I am getting seg faults in the 2 posted above which makes no sense to me because its like, it already stored 400k values, why would it seg fault at 405k

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger to find out where the crash is and why it happens? #including cpp files is generally not the right way to do things. Maybe try and narrow it down to a smaller example all in one block. What you've shown can't be compiled or tested without a fair amount of work.

Comment: Do I use an online debugger or do i download or what, never used one before

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using puttys g++ compiler because I have to run everything through my schools system

Comment: You free allocated memory with delete and then access it. Not ok. Crash is understandable.

Comment: i see that now, so how am i supposed to change all the elements in s, and increase the size without deleting s

Comment: You can allocate the new one and copy and THEN delete...

Comment: I just got rid of the deletion of s and it seemed to work

Comment: You’re probably leaking memory now.

Comment: Not the cause of the _current_ crash, but your `pop` functions will try to return `s[-1]` when emptying the stack.